# Передача массива из js в php: в чем ошибка?

Tags: jquery, post, php, javascript

Есть массив, заполнялся инфой (проверено):

```
var notarius = [];

for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    notarius[i] = [];
    notarius[i]["name"] = jQuery(data).find("name" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["not_type"] = jQuery(data).find("not_type" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["time"] = jQuery(data).find("time" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["phone"] = jQuery(data).find("phone" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["address"] = jQuery(data).find("address" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["licen"] = jQuery(data).find("licen" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["date"] = jQuery(data).find("date" + i).text();
}
```

Данные в нем есть точно. Передаю с помощью post:

```
jQuery.post("/notary/write_in.php", {
    notar: notarius,
    count: count,
    type: 'save',
    city: city,
},

function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Получаем:

```
$notary=$_POST['notar'];
echo $notary[0]["name"];
```

Итог - пустота. Что я перепутала?

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Подсчитала с помощью count количество элементов в массиве $notary получилось 12, столько и должно было в принципе их и быть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы немного не правильно определили переменные, вернее их тип. Вместо квадратных скобок надо использовать фигурные, что означает создание объекта в js. и в самом начале цикла for надо инициализировать переменную i.
Получится так:

```
var notarius = {};

for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    notarius[i] = {};
    notarius[i]["name"] = jQuery(data).find("name" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["not_type"] = jQuery(data).find("not_type" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["time"] = jQuery(data).find("time" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["phone"] = jQuery(data).find("phone" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["address"] = jQuery(data).find("address" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["licen"] = jQuery(data).find("licen" + i).text();
    notarius[i]["date"] = jQuery(data).find("date" + i).text();
}
```

Отправка данных:

```
jQuery.post("/notary/write_in.php", {
    'notar': notarius,
    'count': count,
    'type': 'save',
    'city': city,
},
function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало